# OpenID for CodeIgniter Apps

Tags: codeigniter, openid, codeigniter-2

So I'm building a `cloud` platform to handle a bunch of **CodeIgniter** Apps.
The idea is to ***share*** credentials between those apps, so the user can purchase **App1** and **App2** with the same `account`.
One `process` can be described like :

- The user view the Site : http://myapps.tld
- The user creates an account on http://myapps.tld
- The user browses apps on http://myapps.tld/apps
- The user purchases App1 && App2
- there is a registration form on the main site (let say 'http://myapps.tld')
- The user enter his same credentiels (of http://myapps.tld) on http://myapp1.tld and http://myapp2.tld

The authentication on http://myapps.tld is coded from scratch (very basic one).
I think that a way of achieving this is to use an **OpenID** mechanism built on http://openid.myapps.tld and whenever a user have the need to authenticate with an app from the platform he will be redirected to openid.myapps.tld to confirm/verify his credentials and redirected back to his app ***completely*** identified.

Is **OpenID** the right choice for me ? can I rely on it to handle authentications on the main site and the different apps ?

If so, I've seen a library or two for implementing OpenID on CI 2 but if you have some tips/tutorials, I'll appreciate the sharing :)

I'm thinking also of adding the same OpenID mechanism for 'forum/wiki/blog' tools/services so again the user/client wouldn't have to create multiple accounts to use whatever service/app on the platform.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of OpenID, so - Yes, it's the right choice.  -  http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+openid+tutorial

Comment: Sure, I'm googling like hell, and reading some interesting posts, so yeah OpenID FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID is the way to go. There are a couple of sparks on getsparks.org:

The latest oauth2 is the probably the best option.
http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show

Comment: As seen on github repo `This is only to authenticate onto OAuth2 providers and not to build an OAuth2 service`. I need my `coreApp` to be an **OpenID Provider** and the `OtherApps` As **OpenID Consumers** . I'll go with your proposition as the `Consumer` and [CI-2-OAuth-2-Server](https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server) as the `Provider`